# Convert a Column to datetime where some values are not dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which there is a column `grn_date` which consists of some datetime values and some "-" because earlier i filled it up like this:

```
    df['grn_date'].fillna('-', inplace=True)
```

Earlier I was doing this for the whole columns:

```
    # Format the 'date' column to match the rest of the dates
    df['grn_date'] = df['grn_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00')

    # Calculate the "Cycle time" by subtracting 'grn_date' from 'date'
    df['allot_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['allot_date'])  # Ensure 'grn_date' is in datetime format
    df['grn_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['grn_date'])  # Ensure 'date' is in datetime format

    # Calculate the difference and store it in a new column 'Cycle time'
    df['Cycle time'] = (df['grn_date'] - df['allot_date']).dt.days

    df['grn_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['grn_date']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    df['allot_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['allot_date']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

But now it'll give the error `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`. Do i have to loop over the column and do a try and except or is there any other way to do this?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend copy/reports/views.py", line 1421, in get
    df['grn_date'] = df['grn_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00')
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5575, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py", line 182, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/accessors.py", line 509, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
[30/Oct/2023 09:09:16] "GET /rfid-reportsdownload-1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17740
```

Comment: Dates are binary values, they have no format. There's no if or but about this. As far as `grn_date` is concerned all this code *introduces* localization bugs. If you want to truncate the time part, all you need is `df['grn_date']=df['grn_date'].dt.date`. If you get conversion errors it means the data loaded into `grn_date` is dirty and needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: How was this data loaded? `df['grn_date'].fillna('-', inplace=True)` means that `grn_date` isn't a date column. If the data is loaded from CSV files you can add `-` to the list of `na_values` and avoid having to parse dates after the fact. If there are other dirty values you'll have to find them and handle them. You can't just tread `bananas` or `N/A` as a date

Comment: @Rahul Sharma, seems like you just need to move back `df['grn_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['grn_date'])` before the line that triggers the error. And maybe also, remove `df['grn_date'].fillna('-', inplace=True)`. If not, make sure to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal example with three cases, a `nan` value, a valid date and a hyphen.

You can set the `errors` property of the conversion function to either `ignore`, `coerce` or `raise` to suit your needs. See docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Choose `coerce` to produce a valid Date Series from an invalid Series containing strings. Then, invalid data is replaced by `NaT` (not a time) and the accessor `dt` will work.

As you already observed, a Series containing mixed data (a Series of Objects), won't allow you to use `.dt` notation

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, "2023-10-30", "-"], columns=["date-col"])
df["date-col"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date-col"], errors="coerce")

df["date-col"].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

output is

```
0          NaT
1   2023-10-30
2          NaT
Name: date-col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I have added the traceback. this is where I am getting the error `df['grn_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00')`

Comment: and you are getting the error because you have a Series of objects, not a Series of Timestamps. If you use `pd.to_datetime(YOUR_SERIES).dt.strftime(...)` it should work

Comment: also, providing minimal examples that can be copy and pasted are much appreciated ;-)